# How to normalize input of neural network if you don't know the data in advance

Tags: neural-networks, normalization

Assume my data come on the go and I use them to train my neural network. The data are unbound (xyz coordinates actually). How to normalize the input then ?

Comment: Sounds like, this is an online learning question. Possible duplicate:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261940/how-do-i-normalize-data-in-online-learning  Though my suggestion would be fit the normalising transform in certain steps, maybe 10 times the arrival rate depending on how statistics of the online data changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I normalize data in online learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261940/how-do-i-normalize-data-in-online-learning)

Comment: @MehmetSüzen

Thanks, I couldn't find the previous one. Anyway it looks like there's very limited number of solutions